# How to get files in Mac equivalent of XLSTART folder to be opened "invisibly"

Tags: excel, launch

I have a Utilities file which contains a number of macros which I use a lot.  My old Excel loads this file on launch, but does not show the window.  This is exactly the desired behaviour.

However I recently updated my Excel (16.56 on Big Sur) and now, when Excel launches, the window shows.

Is there any way to make it be invisible?  I've tried deleting all the worksheets but Excel won't let me.  Googling is throwing up scads of completely useless hits and nothing here seems to be relevent, either.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after much more Googling, I found the answer.  Menu item **Window** -> **Hide**.  Then quit Excel, answering **Yes** to save the file.  On relaunch it opens invisibly.